# C++, what is the purpose of argument type (void*&)?

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand a certain code where I found something hard to understand for me.

```
void BPlusTree::GetKey(int key, void*& keyloc) const {
    keyloc = keys + key * attrLength;
    return 0;
}
```

This function calculates the location (memory address) of the key value and store it at `keyloc` variable.

`void*&` means the reference for a void pointer.

And here reference is used to reflect the changed value of `keyloc` to the outer function which called `GetKey.

Am I right till now?

So I thought that, in the main function, when it calls `GetKey` function. It needs to pass `(void*)` not the `(void*&)`.

```
int main() {
.....
int currPos = 0;
char* key = NULL;
int result = currNode->GetKey(currPos, (void*&) key);
}
```

Why is `(void*&)` used instead of `(void*)` here?

Thank you.

// And I added here example code...

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int &a, int &b) {
a = 10;
b = 20;
}

void foo2(int* &c, int* &d) {
*c = 10;
*d = 20;
}

void foo3(void* &c, void* &d) {
*(int*)c = 10;
*(int*)d = 20;
}

int main(void) {
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int* c = new int;
int* d = new int;
void* e = malloc(sizeof(int));
void* f = malloc(sizeof(int));

foo(a, b);
printf("A is %d and B is %d\n", a, b);

foo2(c, d);
printf("C is %d and D is %d\n", *c, *d);

foo3((void*&)c,(void*&) d);     // It works fine
printf("C is %d and D is %d\n", *c, *d);

foo3((void*)c,(void*) d);       // But it does not work
printf("C is %d and D is %d\n", *c, *d);
}
```

Is the (void*) problematic one?? :D

Comment: If it was void*, key would be a copy of the original void*, and that means when keyloc is modified, a copy is modified, not the original key. Since key is a reference to the original, original key is modified (assigned to)

Comment: @nurettin Surely that applies to the parameter. But is it really necessary to cast the *argument* to `void*&` (rhetorical question)?

Comment: Please post some real, self-contained code that compiles.

Comment: @juanchopanza I added an example code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're pretty much right in what you do understand. For the last bit, perhaps it'll be easier to use a pointer instead of a reference in explaining...

You could have had

```
void BPlusTree::GetKey(int key, void** keyloc) const { ... };
```

and a caller

```
char* key = NULL;
int result = currNode->GetKey(currPos, (void**) &key);
```

Here, it should be obvious why you cannot use `&(void*) key`: `(void*) key` is an rvalue, and you cannot take its address. It'd be like taking the address of `(key + 0)`. Sure, `key + 0` is always just `key`, but the mere fact that you have an addition there means you're looking at a copy of the pointer value, not the original pointer object.

When dealing with references, there is not an explicit "address of" operation like there is with pointers, but the problem is the same. `GetKey(currPos, (void*) key)` doesn't work because `(void*) key` is an rvalue, not an lvalue. `(void*&) key` casts `key` to "reference to `void*`", and pretty much means `*(void**) &key`. It is done to pretend that `key` was actually defined as `void*`.

Note: this is generally considered very bad practice. `key` would be better actually defined as `void*`, and then no cast is required to call `GetKey`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!
Ia it a specific situation only for (void*) ??
I think I need to study (void*) before use it...

Comment: @SeongYunKo It's a general problem when you store data in a certain data type, and attempt to pass it by reference (or pointer) to a function expecting a different data type.